# How can I change my textfield on input change calculated by a function?

Tags: jquery, function, calculator, timecodes

This is my timecode calculator. When I change the input field value, then also the timecode should change.

```js
var fps = 25;
var currentFrame =  $('.timecode_input').val();
var SS = Math.floor(currentFrame / fps);
var MM = Math.floor(SS / 60);
var HH = Math.floor(MM / 60);
var FF = currentFrame - (SS * fps);

function pad(str, width, what, left) {
    str = String(str);
    what = String(what);
    var w = width - str.length;

    if (left) {
        return (new Array(w + 1)).join(what) + str;
    } else {
        return str + (new Array(w + 1)).join(what);
    }
}

var i,
    timecode = [HH, MM, SS, FF];

for (i = 0; i < timecode.length; i += 1) {
    timecode[i] = pad(timecode[i], 2, 0, true);
}

var resultString = timecode.join(':'); // HH:MM:SS:FF

var timecode_p = document.querySelector('.timecode_output'),
    input = document.querySelector('.timecode_input');

function setText(v){
    timecode_p.innerHTML = resultString;
     console.log(resultString);
}

input.addEventListener('input', function(){ 
    setText( this.value );
    console.log(this.value );
})

setText(input.value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="timecode_input" type="text" value="25" style="width:90%"> Frames
<p class="timecode_output" style="margin-top:10px"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this code needs to be inside a function and get recalled on the event (maybe not the var definitions).

That is because the event is only calling the setText method which updates the innerHTML property.  It never actually changes your timecode variable.

```
var fps = 25;
var currentFrame =  $('.timecode_input').val();
var SS = Math.floor(currentFrame / fps);
var MM = Math.floor(SS / 60);
var HH = Math.floor(MM / 60);
var FF = currentFrame - (SS * fps);


var i,
    timecode = [HH, MM, SS, FF];

for (i = 0; i < timecode.length; i += 1) {
    timecode[i] = pad(timecode[i], 2, 0, true);
}

var resultString = timecode.join(':'); // HH:MM:SS:FF
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! In your example. How do you mean the example you posted, because it is without function

Comment: I didn't post one...just described the process...with 1632 I figured you'd understand the concept...do you need the exact JavaScript?

Comment: Ah, I put it into this function `function setText(v){` and this seems to work